# How to implement the request and response in php

Tags: php

I have URL like this, how we recive the value
like "`abc.org/result.php?rq=[1,2,3,4]&rq1=[5]`" etc

Can any one help me to convert `rq into array` when recive the value in `result.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `explode()` & `array_map()`

```
$rq = $_GET['rq'];

$arr = array_map(function($v){ return trim($v, ' []');}, explode(',', $rq));

print '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
print '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_decode` to convert into array

```
$a = json_decode($_GET['rq']);
print_r($a);//Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get request also:

```
Abc.com?req[]=1&req[]=2

$_GET['req']
Return 
(1,2)
```